# Missing realization in Factory Method?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

In the class diagram of the design pattern Factory method I think there should be a realization between the abstract creator class and the interface. The factory method returns an object of the type of the interface but there isn't a realization line.
In the following diagram you can see the class diagram generated by the plugin UML in Netbeans:

[image: Factory Method class diagram]

Comment: "the class diagram of the design pattern Factory method" - in what source? I am sure there are hundreds of class diagrams showing the *Factory method* design pattern around the world.

Comment: The plugin UML for Netbeans generates class diagram of design patterns using the Gof diagrams. This is the one that you can see in the attached file

Comment: I guess a dependency is what should be added. A realization would be wrong.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

The `Creator` does not implement the interface, so a realization would be inappropriate. A dependency would work, though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a dependency as Jim says.